# Magento 2 How to override framework feed file?

Tags: magento2, overrides, magento-framework

I am trying to override **Magento Framework** `Feed.php` file,

After googling alot I found how to override framework file but that's not worked for me.

> Please give me the right eay to override framework feed file.

**Vendor/Namespace/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\App\Feed" type="Serole\Corefiles\App\Feed" />
</config>
```

**Vendor/Namespace/App/Feed.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Namespace\App;

use Zend\Feed\Writer\FeedFactory;

/**
 * Default XML feed class
 */
class Feed extends \Magento\Framework\App\Feed
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $feeds;

    /**
     * Feed constructor.
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(array $data)
    {
        $this->feeds = $data;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getFormattedContent() : string
    {
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($this->feeds); die();
        return FeedFactory::factory($this->feeds)->export(FeedFactoryInterface::FORMAT_RSS);
    }
}
```

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process which I follwed in my question is correct, it started working with this solution,

I was trying to override it in an existing module where I did other functionalities, but when I create a new module for overriding, it worked there. I don't know the difference between both of those modules but it solved my problem.

This answer is strange but it worked for me.